# Angularjs src="{{url}} doesn't work in one file but works in another.

Tags: angularjs

I'm learning angular, and have this weird problem: my index includes:

```
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
<script src="js/directives.js"></script>
```

And I have this code:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []).directive('myYoutube', function($sce) {
return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: { code:'=',add:'=' },
    replace: true,
    template: '<div style="height:400px;"><iframe style="overflow:hidden;height:100%;width:100%" width="100%" height="100%" src ="{{url}}" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe></div>',
    link: function (scope) {
        console.log('here');
        scope.$watch('code', function (newVal) {
            if ($sce.isEnabled()){
                console.log('and');}
            if (newVal) {
                console.log('there');
                scope.url= $sce.trustAsResourceUrl("http://www.youtube.com/embed/" + newVal);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

});

When I put it in `controllers.js` it runs fine. But when I put it in `directives.js`, I get this error:

> GET `http://localhost:8000/app/%7B%7Burl%7D%7D` 404 (Not Found)

Which points out that {{url}} isn't evaluated. The question is why?

,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ng-src](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc) instead:

> Using Angular markup like {{hash}} in a src attribute doesn't work
>   right: The browser will fetch from the URL with the literal text
>   {{hash}} until Angular replaces the expression inside {{hash}}. The
>   ngSrc directive solves this problem.

Comment: It works, thanks. But what bothers me more is why the original code did work when in controllers.js

Comment: @user3691475: I don't know how you use it in your controller.js. Using `src` is buggy due to timing problem. It's recommended to use ng-src